# ESLint / Prettier -- enforce max-len / printWidth, but don't require it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, lint, prettier

Is there a way to configure ESLint w/ Prettier to enforce the max-len / printWidth rule but not require it? That is to say, allow you to add line breaks as you see fit?

```
// eslintrc.js

"max-len": [0, 160, 2, { ignoreUrls: true }],

// prettier.config.js

module.exports = {
  trailingComma: "all",
  tabWidth: 2,
  semi: true,
  singleQuote: false,
  printWidth: 160,
};
```

Comment: What do you mean *"not require"*? It's not like it makes you write all lines to exactly 160 characters.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I have my IDE set to autofix on save and if an elements with five or six attributes CAN fit within my max len, it auto corrects it and "forces" it. I don't want to turn off autofix-on-save, and even if I do, I get little underlines wherever there's an "unnecessary" line break (which I in fact want).

Comment: Then you likely don't want prettier's printWidth: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width. Or maybe prettier, if you have a layout you "want".

Comment: Prettier kind of sucks in this way. It does indeed "make you write lines to [not exactly but near] 160 characters". Ideally, it would apply printWidth to only lines that were too long, but not make lines longer that are too short.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `print-width` to 999 in prettier to turn it off, then set the eslint `max-len` rule to be a warning at what ever your preferred value is.

Comment: Your `max-len` rule should be formatted like this `'max-len': [1, { code: 100 }],` for instance to set the line width of `code`, where 1 tells eslint to warn when longer than 100

Comment: Setting print-width to 999 does not turn it off, it tells Prettier that each line should aim at being 999 characters long. If you've got a max-len rule with ESLint there is going to be a conflict between these two rules.

Comment: With ESLint the last plugin wins. You should always include prettier last as it conflicts with half the eslint standard rule set.

Comment: I set `"printWidth": 999,` in my `.prettierrc` and I set `'max-len': 'off',` in `.eslintrc.cjs` and it now formats long lines in one line BUT it 1) still yells at me saying to replace the spaces with newlines `eslint(prettier/prettier)` AND 2) if I want to make a new line it FORCES me to put it back to one when I format... How can I tell eslint and prettier to just leave me alone in terms of line length?

Comment: Personally, I prefer using `Infinity` as print width value.